# User-vs-User Rankings Model

Tags: mysql, algorithm, statistics

I have a `users` table, and I want to assign each user a ranking based on their performance in a battle against another user.

I would just do a simple win/loss calculator, but I don't want a user to just repeatedly beat a user with a very low rank and progress to #1.

I have no real knowledge in algorithms so I'm not sure how I would proceed to do this.

Does anyone know of an algorithm such that a user will be ranked on their performance against users of similar ranks?

Thanks!

Comment: Which options did you consider, and how do they fail to meet your overall requirements? Please review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To your specific concern: "I don't want a user to just repeatedly beat a user with a very low rank and progress to #1":

Instead of always transferring one point from the loser to the winner on every game, a simple approach might be to transfer a point scaled by the difference in player ranks. This reflect that the weaker the opponent, the less meaningful the victory:

```
if (winner.score <= loser.score) {   /* defeated a stronger player - yay! */
    winner.score += 1;
    loser.score -= 1;
}
else {   /* defeated a weaker player */
    float value = 1.0 / (winner.score - loser.score);
    winner.score += value;
    loser.score -= value;
}
```

(You'll probably have to use a stored program to implement this in MySQL - it seems too horrendous to try to implement in a single SQL UPDATE statement.)

For a more thoughtful approach to ranking players, why not take a look at how chess players rank each other: [wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_rating_system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_rating_system)